# Problems in handling pagination in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a mysql database and I am using jquery to do a live search which is working like a charm. But I have tried alot of ways to have a pagenation for my search results.

Below is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*
     Set the inner html of the table, tell the user to enter a search term to get started.
     We could place this anywhere in the document. I chose to place it
     in the table.
    */
    $.get('data/search-data.php', function(returnData) {
        $('#results').html(returnData);
    });

    /* When the user enters a value such as "j" in the search box
     * we want to run the .get() function. */
    $('#searchData').keyup(function() {

        /* Get the value of the search input each time the keyup() method fires so we
         * can pass the value to our .get() method to retrieve the data from the database */
        var searchVal = $(this).val();

        /* If the searchVal var is NOT empty then check the database for possible results
         * else display message to user */
        if(searchVal !== '') {

            /* Fire the .get() method for and pass the searchVal data to the
             * search-data.php file for retrieval */
            $.get('data/search-data.php?searchData='+searchVal, function(returnData) {

                /* If the returnData is empty then display message to user
                 * else our returned data results in the table.  */
                if (!returnData) {
                    $('#results').html('<p style="padding:5px;">Search term entered does not return any data.</p>');
                } else {
                    $('#results').html(returnData);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.get('data/search-data.php?searchData='+searchVal, function(returnData) {
                 $('#results').html(returnData);
            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I would return a static html with some `div`s representing each page, show the first and hide the others, then jquery will count them, render the paging links, and handle the show/hide on click

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution, without delving into javascript object and/or templating is returning the pages from the server like this:

```
<div data-page="1" class="results">
    <ul>
        <li>Result 1</li>
        <li>Result 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-page="2" class="hidden results">
    <ul>
        <li>Result 3</li>
        <li>Result 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-page="3" class="hidden results">
    <ul>
        <li>Result 4</li>
        <li>Result 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

then create the pager links with jquery on the ajax callback:

```
var links = [];
$('.results').each(function(i) {
    var link = $('<a />', {
        text: i+1,
        href: '#'
    });
    links.push(link);
});
$('#pager').html(links);
```

then a click handler will toggle the display of the pages:

```
$('#pager').on('click', 'a', function() {
   var i = $(this).index(); 
    $('.results').eq(i).removeClass('hidden').siblings('.results').addClass('hidden');
    return false;
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Ry7NJ/1/

Comment: Cool I will try this and see how far I will go. Thanks. I will definitely give you feedback.